# PHP regex for $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]

Tags: php, regex, get

I am matching pairs in regex. `$pairs[1]` will contain the part before `=` and `$pairs[2]` will contain the part after `=` .

When it gets to `&startrow`  it should start skips rest and start making another pair.

```
$query= "link=http://abcd.com&efgh&lmkn&startrow=20"

preg_match_all('/(\w+)=([^&startrow]+)/', $query, $pairs);
```

The above regex stops at `&` but not at `&startrow`

Expected Output

```
$pairs[1][0] = link
$pairs[2][0] = http://abcd.com&efgh&lmkn


$pairs[1][1] =startrow
$pairs[2][1] =20
```

Comment: Abso-bloody-lutely unclear.

Comment: @revo sorry, english is my third language, i'm still learning it. I edited my question, i hope you can understand it now

Comment: What should be the output when there is `&startrow` or is not in url? Please show expected output in both cases.

Comment: @revo edited answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following regex:

```
(\w+)=((?:(?!&startrow).)+)
```

You are able to catch both parts separately:

```
preg_match_all('~(\w+)=((?:(?!&startrow).)+)~', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

PHP output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => link=http://abcd.com&efgh&lmkn
            [1] => link
            [2] => http://abcd.com&efgh&lmkn
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => startrow=20
            [1] => startrow
            [2] => 20
        )

)
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/5jNGn)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression for this; you need [parse_str()](https://secure.php.net/parse_str):

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $params = null;
php > parse_str('link=http://abcd.com&efgh&lmkn&startrow=20', $params);
php > var_dump($params);
php shell code:1:
array(4) {
  'link' =>
  string(15) "http://abcd.com"
  'efgh' =>
  string(0) ""
  'lmkn' =>
  string(0) ""
  'startrow' =>
  string(2) "20"
}
```

Comment: Check question again, i added expected output

Comment: Your expected output is incorrect; `http://abcd.com&efgh&lmkn` is not a valid URL.

Comment: but i want it, I've link as a query

Comment: StackOverflow is about knowledge sharing, you're treating it as a code writing service, which it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why that would make sense, but assuming all you request are well formed and valid, you could do something plain and simple like this ;)

```
$_GET_RAW = [];
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    // split query string into key value pairs
    foreach (explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) as $keyValueString) {
        // separate key and value
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $keyValueString);
        $_GET_RAW[$key]    = $value;
    }
}
```